# How can i make a tkinter Label not ajust the column size using Grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I need to add a black bar at the top of my program window containing the title, for an example have a look at the top of this webpage - There is a header, that is basically what i want for everyone of my windows for my tkinter program. Is there anyway i can set a default for every one of the new windows that i create? or is there a default format i can creat that will automatically be asigned to each window/page?

I have tried using a label to stretch across the screen like so:

```
label1 = tkinter.Label(window, text="Title            ",bg="black",fg="white")
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

I also tried other things but the problem with that is that it ajusts the grid's column size, meaning i can only have one column of widgets.

Just for reference i am 14 and still learning the basics so i use a simple kind of way of using tkinter.

This is an example of how basic i use tkinter so please be patient with me haha.

```
#How i create main window.
window1 = tkinter.Tk()
#Insert window1 configurations(e.g, title, background, icon)

#How i create new windows
window2 = tkinter.TopLevel()
#Insert window2 configurations(e.g, title, background, icon)
window2.withdraw()

#How i open a new window
def openwindow():
    window1.withdraw
    window2.update
    window2.deiconify
```

Now the problem i have is within this code:

```
#New page
def SongPage():
    MainMenu.withdraw()
#Newpage
def OptionsPage():
    MainMenu.withdraw()



#MainMenu window.
MainMenu = tkinter.Tk()

MainMenu.geometry("200x150")

MainMenu.configure(background="grey")

MainMenu.title("Title")

#This is the header.(It has spaces to make it spread across screen)
MenuTitle = tkinter.Label(MainMenu, text="Header             ",bg="black", 
                         fg="white",font=("Times",20,"bold"))
#This is a small subheader.(It has spaces to make it spread across screen)
MenuSub = tkinter.Label(MainMenu, text="   Subheading                                          
                   ",bg="grey34", fg="white",font=("Times",10,"bold"))

#These "space" labels are to just space things out.
space3 = tkinter.Label(MainMenu, text="",bg="grey", fg="white",
                          font=("Times",20,"bold"))
space4 = tkinter.Label(MainMenu, text="",bg="grey", fg="white",
                          font=("Times",20,"bold"))

#These are the two buttons i'd like to be on screen under headers.
SongButton = tkinter.Button(MainMenu, text="Songs", bg="grey",fg="black",
                            font=("Times",12),command=SongPage)
OptionsButton = tkinter.Button(MainMenu, text="Options", bg="grey",fg="black",
                               font=("Times",12),command=OptionsPage)


#This is applying the widgets to the window.
MenuTitle.grid(row=0,column=0)
MenuSub.grid(row=1,column=0)
SongButton.grid(row=3,column=0)
OptionsButton.grid(row=3,column=1)
```

Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like:
https://pasteboard.co/HZKnIR9.png

Here is what i want it to look like:
https://pasteboard.co/HZKo1Ru.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the columnspan keyword argument in your call to .grid().  Then you can use the sticky keyword to make sure it touches the left and right edges of the columns.  For example:

```
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
```

will cause your label to extend across both column 0 and column 1.  If your window has only two columns then your black bar will always extend all the way across.  If you have more than two columns you need a bigger number for columnspan.

Tkinter will calculate the width of all the columns by using the size of the other widgets first.  If your black bar is so big that it needs more space then TkInter will have to stretch the other column widths.  But probably that won't be necessary and the black bar will just go nicely all the way across the window, which is what you want.

See the documentation here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html

Comment: I know it is a very late reply, but this was very helpful at the time. I know a lot more about tkinter now and would like to thank you for the answer, Thank you! :)